# Adding include in LINQ query based on condition in .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have the following LINQ Query where I want to include based on the condition. However this does not seem to add to the initial query. How do i go about fixing it?

```
var fruits = context.Fruits
            .Where(w => w.ColorId == colorId && Status.Contains(w.Status))
            .OrderBy(ob => ob.FruitName).ThenBy(tb1 => tb1.FiruitName);

if(model.Red)
{
    fruits.Include(i => i.Taste);
}

if(model.Blue)
{
    fruits.Include(i => i.Sour)
    .ThenInclude(i => i.Sweet);
}

var fruitList = fruits.ToList();
```

The fruitList only contains the initial query result and not the if conditions even though it goes inside the if loop during debugging.

EDIT 1 :
I tried the below code but it throws a cast error and explicit casting still ends up throwing an error.

```
fruits = fruits.Include(i => i.Taste);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any other Linq statement, it should be

```
fruits = fruits.Include(i => i.Taste);
```

since it is like a constructor which adds up to the previous statement

To resolve type issue, move order by statements to the end. These lines should be changed from

```
var fruits = context.Fruits
            .Where(w => w.ColorId == colorId && Status.Contains(w.Status))
            .OrderBy(ob => ob.FruitName).ThenBy(tb1 => tb1.FiruitName);
```

to

```
var fruits = context.Fruits
            .Where(w => w.ColorId == colorId && Status.Contains(w.Status));
```

And this line

```
var fruitList = fruits.ToList();
```

should be changed to

```
var fruitList = fruits
    .OrderBy(ob => ob.FruitName).ThenBy(tb1 => tb1.FiruitName)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This fruits = fruits.Include(i => i.Taste); throws a casting error and adding an explicit cast does not help.

Comment: please see update